# Is it possible to use the audio from external apps (eg. Spotify) running in the background as input to AvCaptureInput when developing an iOS App?

Tags: ios, swift

I've looked through all the posts online and the Apple Developer Documentation, but nothing seems to comment on this. I want to be able to live-record the audio coming from, say, Spotify or another app that's running in the background, and process this audio data in my own app. This seems to be [possible on Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/av-capture).

I haven't actually coded it out yet but I've read through the documentation fully and previous stackoverflow posts.